# What are specific proofs of Jacobi Triple Product Identity?

Tags: combinatorics, theta-functions, q-series

I am looking for the Special Proofs.
Here is a reference from MSE.
[Motivation for/history of Jacobi's triple product identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434959/motivation-for-history-of-jacobis-triple-product-identity)

I also know that a simple proof via Functional Equation  from the book of An Invitation to q-series Hei-Chi-Chan. it has a very nice explanation , step by step.  I also have learnt that Zeilberg's recursive proof.

What are the other interesting proofs about this identity you know? ? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I find the proof by Jacobi in _Fundamenta Nova_ to be much simpler and elegant. I have presented the same in my [blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0).

Comment: its very good proof. thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a combinatorial proof of Jacobi's Triple Identity see the article by [Kolitsch](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-016-9854-5).

For an elementary number-theoretic proof see the article by [Herbert S. Wilf](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/SLC/wpapers/s42wilf.pdf), which also has references for other proofs.

For a standard proof see for example [here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edmjackso/CO630/JTPID.pdf).

Another well-known proof is by [Andrews](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-02/S0002-9939-1965-0171725-X/), using Euler's identities.

Comment: that's a  great answer. thanks:)