# Problem with rigorous Jacobi Triple Product proof.

Tags: complex-analysis

My only problem is this step:

From making this:

$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nz^nq^{n^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}z^nq^{n^2}={A^2(q)\over A(q^2)}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nz^{2n}q^{2n^2}\tag1$

To this:

$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nq^{2n^2}={A^2(q)\over A(q^2)}\tag2$

in this proof:
[Motivation for/history of Jacobi's triple product identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434959/motivation-for-history-of-jacobis-triple-product-identity?newreg=b809d1d18ffd4a67a22590d0e56639cd)

(It starts with:

"I would like to offer very elementary proof for Jacobi Triple Product Identity. It is very direct way proof and elementary proof.")

Could someone prove this a bit more concretely and rigorously?

Comment: I mean the line where it says:
"if we focus z0
 term and we multiply in left side. We get that"